# C: is there any benefit in using for(;;)?

Tags: c

I found this implementation for `char * strchr (const char *string, int c);`:

```
for (;;) 
  if (*string == c)
    return (char *) string;
  else if (*string == '\0')
    return NULL;
  else
    string++;
```

For me, though, it would be equivalent to do the following, which would be way easier to read:

```
while (*string != c && *string != '\0')
  string++;

return (*string == c) ? ((char *) string) : (NULL);
```

I take it there is some reason for the libc to implement the first one. But any take on what's the reason behind it?

Comment: As a long-shot, it could be some way to make the code "easier" to optimize by localizing it a bit more, and re-using the same expression's result (`*string`) more closely to the last usage.

Comment: If you're really want to know, put those two codes in a test project in separate functions, and compare the generated assembly code at different optimization levels. It might turn out their version optimizes better?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Visual Studio doesn't like `while(1)` when you bump up the warning level to the maximum (especially if you ask it to treat warnings as errors), but is OK with `for(;;)`.

Comment: what about while (true) ?

Comment: +1.  For information, the Visual Studio warning is "conditional expression is constant" and also applies to `while (true)`

Comment: @TheBlastOne What kind of difference are you seeing between the two non-zero constants in this context?

Comment: I don´t see any difference. I asked if there might be one. As simonc said, there is none.

Comment: @TheBlastOne I don't either. For the purpose of checking whether the conditional expression is 0 or not and whether it's constant or not they are identical.